# The method 'collection' was called on null. Receiver null Tried calling: collection("user")

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

```
  getProfileDetailFromFirestore(String token) {
    firebaseFirestore.collection("user").doc(token).snapshots().listen((value) {
      profileDataSink.add(profileObject.fromMapObject(value.data()));
    });
  }

  Future<void> followOrUnFollowUser(String selfToken, String friendToken,
      ProfileObject self, ProfileObject friend, bool isUserFollowing) async {
    await firebaseFirestore.collection("user").doc(selfToken).update({
      "following": isUserFollowing
          ? FieldValue.arrayRemove([friend.toMapLimitedData()])
          : FieldValue.arrayUnion([friend.toMapLimitedData()]),
    });
    await firebaseFirestore.collection("user").doc(friendToken).update({
      "follower": isUserFollowing
          ? FieldValue.arrayRemove([self.toMapLimitedData()])
          : FieldValue.arrayUnion([self.toMapLimitedData()]),
    });
  }

  dispose() {
    _postCreatedController.close();
    _profileObjectController.close();
  }
}
```

Here is a my code, I am getting the error in the title whenever I try to click on a button my app to see my unique profile.

Comment: It seems like `firebaseFirestore` is `null` in one of the calls you shared. Running the code in the debugger is the easiest way to find out precisely where that happens.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure to [Initialize](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) the FirebaseApp:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  ...
}
```

- Make sure (firebaseFirestore.collection("user")...) to be like :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(token).snapshots().listen((event) {
 // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because the `firebaseFirestore` is null.

Ensure you define the `firebaseFirestore` variable.

You can do that like this:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```